# Question about heteroscedascity and point estimates

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, heteroscedasticity

Let's say I am running a regression:

$y_{j}=\beta x_{j} + \eta_j$

and $var(y_i|x_i)=var(\eta_i|x_i)=f(x_i)$, say the variance is increasing in x. assume $\eta$ is fully independent of x, so consistency/unbiasedness hold.

So even though ols is unbiased, would this still potentially draw a drastically different point estimate than the case where the variance was homoscedastic? like say for arbitrary obersvation j, $E[\eta_j^2]$ is very very large (e.g., say j is a state, and Y are state averages, and state j has a very very small population, driving the variance up). would then in my sample one large draw from state j significantly alter the regression coefficient? It is just hard for me to reconcile this existing with the estimtor still being unbiased. Is that just the consequence of the hetereoscadascity? if i can keep getting wildly different draws of $\eta_j$, then the point estimate would also vary widely but on average still be correct?

Comment: Indeed, unbiased refers to being right on average in repeated samples (so if you were to draw many data sets and could compute the estimator each time). Heteroskedasticity affects the variance of the estimator, so is related to how far off the true value you tend to be with any singe estimate.